# I cannot tell what I am doing wrong with this java recursion question! I posted the excercise and my code down bellow

Tags: java, recursion

Write a recursive method indexOf that accepts two Strings as parameters and that returns the starting index of the first occurrence of the second String inside the first String (or -1 if not found). The table below lists several calls to your method and their expected return values. Notice that case matters, as in the last example that returns -1.

```
Call    Value Returned
indexOf("Barack Obama", "Bar")  0
indexOf("Barack Obama", "ck")   4
indexOf("Barack Obama", "a")    1
indexOf("Barack Obama", "McCain")   -1
indexOf("Barack Obama", "BAR")  -1
```

Strings have an indexOf method, but you are not allowed to call it. You are limited to these methods:

Method  Description

```
equals(String other)     //returns true if the two Strings contain the same characters
length()                 //returns the int number of characters in the String
substring(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
substring(int fromIndex) //returns a new String containing the characters from this 
                         //String from fromIndex (inclusive) to toIndex (exclusive), 
                         //or to the end of the String if toIndex is omitted
```

You are not allowed to construct any structured objects other than Strings (no array, List, Scanner, etc.) and you may not use any loops to solve this problem; you must use recursion.

```
public int indexOf(String s, String b){
    if(s.length() <= b.length() && !s.equals(b)){return -1;}
    if(s.substring(0, b.length()).equals(b)){return 0;}
    return 1 + indexOf(s.substring(b.length()), b);
}
```

Comment: I think you want `return 1 + indexOf(s.substring(1), b);` as your last line

Comment: Answer of @sprinter is correct but why do you need do this that way? Why not use `public int indexOf(String str)` of `String.class`

Comment: @QuangNguyen I am practicing recursion, I know that you could use the indexOf method of String class.

Comment: @sprinter why would you use s.substring(1) and It works but not quiet there yet, I cant get it to return -1 when the String 2 is not found

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, it will not work for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Two slight changes to get the answer of FreddyDs working:

```
public static int indexOf(String s, String b){
        if(s.length() <= b.length() && !s.equals(b)){return -1;}
        if(s.substring(0, b.length()).equals(b)){return 0;}
        int result = indexOf(s.substring(1, s.length()), b);
        return result == -1 ? -1 : 1 + result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please explain what the last line does?

Comment: The last line makes sure there is no addition of results of the previous invocations, when there is nothing found,, to get -1 returned for the whole method.